# python docx how to read text that has hyper-link?

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I am using python-docx to transform a word document to txt file. There are some words in the document that has hyper-link. I don't need the link, I only need the text itself. But when I use Paragraph to read it, the text just disappears.

```
 elements = []
    for block in fp.element.body:
        if block.__class__.__name__ == 'CT_P':
            elements.append(('paragraph', block))
        elif block.__class__.__name__ == 'CT_Tbl':
            elements.append(('table', block))

for index, type_el in enumerate(elements):
        element_type, element = type_el[0], type_el[-1]

        # write paragraph into the txt file
        if element_type == 'paragraph':
            paragraph = Paragraph(parse_xml(element.xml), parent=None)
            img = paragraph._element.xpath('.//pic:pic')
            if not img:
                txt = paragraph.text
                if txt != "":
                    txt_file.write(txt + "\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

This was remedied in `python-docx==1.0.0` where `Paragraph.text` includes the text of hyperlinks.

At the time of this writing it is available as `pip install python-docx==1.0.0rc1` but should be available just as `pip install python-docx` by Nov 1 2023.

It also allows accessing hyperlinks directly when you need to know for example where the hyperlink occurs within the rest of the paragraph's text:

```py
from docx.text.hyperlink import Hyperlink
from docx.text.run import Run

...

for item in paragraph.iter_inner_content():
    if isinstance(item, Run):
        ...
    elif isinstance(item, Hyperlink):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlinks are represented as Run objects. You can get the hyperlink text with the following code:

```
for run in paragraph.runs:
    if "hyperlink" in run._element.xml:
        txt_file.write(run.text + "\n")
```